# A problem of calculus.A fly walks with a speed of $1$ cm/sec in every direction of a piece of paper which is considered to be $xy$ plane.......

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

A fly walks with a speed of $1$ cm/sec in every direction of a piece of
paper which is considered to be $xy$ plane. If the fly walks away from the origin
in the direction of $u^{\to} = i − 7j$, the temperature it measures increases at a rate
of $3^{\circ}$C/sec.If the fly walks away from the origin in the direction $v^{\to} = i + j$,the temperature it measures decreases at a rate of $2^{\circ}$C/sec.Find how fast the
temperature changes if the fly moves away from the origin in the positive x axis direction.

This is problem which I have to solve using calculus but I do not know how to solve this using calculus.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: We need some assumption on the distribution of the temperature, otherwise we cannot compute anything. Is the graphics of the temperature assumed to be a plane?

Comment: Yes it is plane.

Comment: Then consider if it flies towards $\vec u$ for 1 second and then towards $\vec v$ for 7 seconds.

Comment: You've been given two directional derivatives of the temperature function, and you're asked to find a third. That's where the calculus comes in.

Comment: Oh wait, it can walk but cannot fly...

Comment: In possitive x axis direction means in the direction $w^{\to}=i$

Comment: $8i=u^{\to}+7v^{\to}$ may be it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the temperature in the origin is zero, the temperature in the point $(1,-7)$ is $3\sqrt{50}$ and the temperature in the point $(1,1)$ is $-2\sqrt{2}$. Since:
$$(8,0)=7(1,1)+(1,-7)$$
the temperature in the point $(8,0)$ is $-14\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt{50}=\sqrt{2}$, so moving in the direction of $(1,0)$ the temperature increases of $\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{2}$ degrees every second.